# Injective function from $(0,1)$ to a partition

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Consider the set $(0,1)$ and denote every $a \in (0,1)$ by it's decimal expansion
$$
a=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots
$$
Now, define the equivalence relation $a \sim b$ if and only if $a_p = b_p$ for every prime number $p$; and let $A$ denote the set of equivalence classes.

Is it possible to establish an injection $f:[0,1]\rightarrow A$?

What I actually want to prove is that is that $|A|=2^{\aleph_0}$. So far, I've been able to prove that $A$ is not countable but that is not enough if one wants to avoid the use of the continuum hypothesis.

Is it actually possible to prove this without using the continuum hypothesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that some numbers have more than one decimal expansion. $0.5=0.4\bar 9$. So for sake of concreteness let us assume that when such situation occurs we choose the expansion ending with an infinite string of $0$'s.

**HINT:** It is in fact *much* **much** ***much*** easier to define an injection from $2^\Bbb N$ into $A$. Given any $f\colon\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}$, map $f$ to the real number $a$ such that for the $n$-th prime number $a_{p_n}=f(n)$, and otherwise $a_k=0$.

Now prove that if $f\neq g$ then they are mapped to distinct real numbers which are not equivalent, and therefore the map is in fact injective into $A$.

Comment: Although your proof is fine, I disagree with the "much, much. much easier" comment. Once you've chosen one decimal expansion for the numbers that have two of them, you can proceed as follows. Given $x\in[0,1]$, obtain $f_0(x)$ by copying the $n$-th digit of $x$ as the $p_n$-th digit of $f_0(x)$, and fill in the rest of the digits of $f_0(x)$ with, say, 3's. Then define $f(x)$ to be the equivalence class in $A$ that contains $f_0(x)$. That's essentially you proof but it avoids $2^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Andreas, you might be right. I feel that somehow whenever expansions of real numbers are discussed it is much much much easier to me to think about binary, or whatever base, strings rather than real numbers.